# How to save each video watched on a streaming site?

Tags: video, streaming, capture

We all watch many streaming videos such as YouTube, Videobb, or others.  Is there any software or application that automatically capture the video while I am watching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Replay Media Catcher](http://applian.com/download-videos/) can do this automatically.

> The Replay Media Catcher software can capture any form of audio and video media found on the web with a click of a button – saving you hundreds of dollars in the long-run for you music lovers out there.
>
> What this means is that you can be watching a music video on Youtube and with the click of a button, have the entire video on your computer in a matter of minutes.  Or if you prefer, you can choose to only capture the audio from the video and have the mp3 file on your computer almost instantly.

[image: Replay Media Catcher]

Answer (score 1):

[Streaming Video Downloader](http://www.binarymark.com/Products/StreamingVideoDownloader/default.aspx) operates exactly as you describe! When you begin watching a video, be it YouTube, live stream, RTMP, or any other supported format, it will automatically start saving it, at the same time showing you a dialog where you can either confirm or cancel the operation. You can also set it up in a fully automatic mode so that not even a confirmation dialog will be shown.

Disclosure: I am one of the authors.

Comment: I'd like to bring your attention to the second part of the faq on promotion "If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons." - you might want to answer questions that are something other than your software

Comment: I understand. But what if it precisely answers the question being asked? Should I refrain from answering altogether?

Comment: BTW, where is that FAQ could you provide a link? I couldn't find it...

Comment: Well, its really much better if you answer *other* questions too - as opposed to just stuff relating to the software you make. I'd like to give you the benefit of the doubt, rather than spamflagging you right away. You can read the site [faq] here, and [here](http://superuser.com/faq#promotion) is the specific section.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is confusing though, as obviously I am more competent with the software I tried, and thus with which I am strongly affiliated, and cannot provide answers if I have not used a particular software. And what is the threshold - how many answers with software recommendations are allowed vs total answers?

Comment: And in addition, this particular question asks for a specific software that can save videos in a specific way. The product I suggested does exactly that and the answer is therefore 100% relevant albeit late. With unclear policies like this, I feel rather discouraged to post any answers here at all, as it appears my account may simply be blocked if the moderators feel like it.

Comment: Its about intent really - there's other users who're software developers who answer other questions. I rather doubt the *only* software you use on a day to day basis are your own products. Its pretty significantly about playing nice and being part of the community. I do think this is a question for [meta], more than here. I will upvote this answer, and SERIOUSLY suggest you ask there for clarification and diversify your answers.

Comment: I certainly understand the rules and ethics behind this. It's just that it should not hurt all those who provide completely relevant answers, albeit recommending the products their worked on. I also did not mean to say that I only work with the products I developed, rather I said that I can only recommend products I used, including those of which I was an author. In any case thank you for your comments and understanding. I will try to provide answers w/o referencing any software I used as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution that captures the video automatically. However, there are several solutions that capture on command. For example [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) for Firefox.